# Iterate through specifics dictionary keys with itemgetter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a diciotnary with the folowing structure:

```
global_results = {
                  'group1': {
                             'Assessnent': "PASSED"
                             ...
                             },
                  'group2': {
                             'Assessment': "PASSED"
                             ...
                             },
                   ...
                  }
```

The point is that I do not know how many groups I have and I need to check if all **assessments = "PASSED"**

So far I have done the following but it looks ugly

```
for key in global_results.keys():
    count=0
    if global_results[key]["Assessment"] == "PASSED":
        count += 1    

if count == len(list(global_results.keys())):
    global_results["FINAL"] = "PASSED"
else: 
    global_results["FINAL"] = "FAILED"
```

I know that `operator.itemgetter` could be useful to simplify code. thanks

Comment: Could you post a valid dictionary?

Comment: This is a generic dicitonary. I am interested in the idea.

Comment: I don't really see a good usecase for `operator.itemgetter` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function to avoid the counting part:

```py
if all(group["Assessment"] == "PASSED" for group in global_results.values()):
    global_results["FINAL"] = "PASSED"
else:
    global_results["FINAL"] = "FAILED"
```

---

Your own code is fine except for a few simplifications that could be done, such as looping the values instead of keys, and the fact that the `len` of the dict itself can be used:

```py
count = 0
for group in global_results.values():
    if group["Assessment"] == "PASSED":
        count += 1    

if count == len(global_results):
    global_results["FINAL"] = "PASSED"
else: 
    global_results["FINAL"] = "FAILED"
```